# Handle form submission in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/accounts/*")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView home() {
        final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        final List<Account> accountsForCurrentUser = this.accountService.getAccountsForCurrentUser();
        modelAndView.addObject("accounts", accountsForCurrentUser);
        modelAndView.setViewName("pages/accounts/index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("create")
    public ModelAndView create() {
        final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("account", new Account());
        modelAndView.setViewName("pages/accounts/create");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping("create")
    public ModelAndView createSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "account") Account account, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return modelAndView;
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/accounts");
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is redirecting user to /accounts/ when the form is validated but taking him back to /accounts/create/ with errors shown if errors has been reported.

But, on error, I have:

> Error resolving template "accounts/create", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: Well, do the same thing as what you're doing in your create() method: set the correct view name in the ModelAndView before returning it.

Answer (score 2):

You also need set model and view name in post/create method.

By the way, handling methods with `ModelAndView` is valid but I think it would be better to use the `String` approach. It's much better to read and a standart way. So your controller will look like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/accounts")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @GetMapping("")
    public String home(Model Model) {
        List<Account> accountsForCurrentUser = this.accountService.getAccountsForCurrentUser();
        model.addAttribute("accounts", accountsForCurrentUser);
        return "pages/accounts/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String newAccount(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("account", new Account());
        return "pages/accounts/create";
    }

    @PostMapping("/new")
    public String createAccount(@Valid @ModelAttribute Account account, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "pages/accounts/create";
        }
        "redirect:/accounts";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works. But, if I add some attribute in newAccount, they are not present anymore in case of errors.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how the attribute is not present? What kind of attribute do you trying to add and what is the error message / stack trace?

Comment: In newAccount(Model model), I added model.attribute to be shown in my view. But if I access this page after an error, this attribute is not map anymore. Actually, I think the model's content is empty.

Comment: There might be errors in your view. Controller should work properly.

Comment: In my controller, I added model.addAttribute("suppliers", suppliers); And in my view, there is 
<select id="suppliers" class="form-control" th:field="*{supplier.id}">
<option th:each="supplier : ${suppliers}" th:text="${supplier.name}" th:value="${supplier.id}"></option>
</select> When I GET access, this select contains several suppliers. But after POST with error, it is empty.

Comment: You just need set related value of `<select>` element if binding result has any errors.

Comment: So I need to set it in my model again?